# Loading XML to table producing nothing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I'm trying to import part of an xml file into a SQL Server database, but while the query successfully executes there is nothing in the table.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<config>
<company>
<Code>0514</Code>
<Name>Company A</Name>
<ContactName>Alan Smith</ContactName>
<ContactTel></ContactTel>
<ContactMail>random@random.net</ContactMail>
<System>type A</System>
</company>
</config>
```

Then here is the query I run

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 'C:\Users\Ramdon\file.xml';
INSERT INTO #tmp_Company2 
SELECT
Code = Events.value('@Code', 'char(6)'),
Name = Events.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)'),
ContactName =Events.value('@ContactName', 'varchar(100)'),
ContactTel =Events.value('@ContactTel', 'varchar(15)'),
ContactMail =Events.value('@ContactMail', 'varchar(100)'),
System =Events.value('@System', 'char(20)'),
FROM @XML.nodes('//config/company') as  XTbl(Events);

select * from #tmp_Company2;
```

Everything I've read suggests it should work but I get nothing.

Comment: Your XML isn't well formed. `<Code>0514</PracticeCode>` should be `<Code>0514</Code>` and there is a missing `<Practice>` after `company` and a missing `</company>` before `</config>`

Comment: What happens when you run the select without the insert?

Comment: @McNets, sorry that was me modifying the original format and missing stuff.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik nothing still selects nothing

Comment: Yeah, what you're doing now won't load an XML file from the file system. You need to start a few steps back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out your XML file isn't well formed. If you can convert your XML text into this:

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <config>
   <company>
     <Practice>
       <Code>0514</Code>
       <Name>Company A</Name>
       <ContactName>Alan Smith</ContactName>
       <ContactTel></ContactTel>
       <ContactMail>random@random.net</ContactMail>
       <SystemType>type A</SystemType>
     </Practice>
   </company>
 </config>';
```

Then you could use next query to get data content:

```
select T2.lin.value('(./Code)[1]', 'char(6)') Code,
       T2.lin.value('(./Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') Name,
       T2.lin.value('(./ContactName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') ContactName,
       T2.lin.value('(./ContactTel)[1]', 'varchar(15)') ContactTel,
       T2.lin.value('(./ContactMail)[1]', 'varchar(100)') ContactMail,
       T2.lin.value('(./SystemType)[1]', 'varchar(100)') System
       into #tmp_Company2
from   @XML.nodes('/config/company/Practice') T2(lin);
```

> ```
> select * from #tmp_Company2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Code   | Name      | ContactName | ContactTel | ContactMail       | System
> :----- | :-------- | :---------- | :--------- | :---------------- | :-----
> 0514   | Company A | Alan Smith  |            | random@random.net | type A
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2134c3f8125775b7b55974b0460ced1d)*

Comment: thank you for this (don't have the karma to upvote this). Also ran into a problem with the encoding, needed to change it to utf-8 for some reason.

Comment: You can use utf-16 if you convert your xml file to NVARCHAR. Have a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fbe4beec6ac40c49e1edf4c3aa055c04

Comment: yeah discovered that when it flashed up the error. Now I just need to work out how to do it to a file rather than text.